# MySQL SELECT version number from Sphinx engine

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

I'm implementing monitoring on a large set of MySQL / Sphinx servers. I want to monitor the version number of Sphinx by using an SQL SELECT query. 
I wanna do this by a SELECT query, because I don't have access to the filesystem of the Sphinx machines, and also a SELECT query would simplify my monitoring implementation.

For example, for the MySQL version number I can use:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'version';
```

Is there any similar workaround to get the Sphinx version, for example by firing a query like

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%sphinx%'; ?
```

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to get it in a SphinxQL command, but when you first connect with the CLI client, the server version is shown

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 2.1.1-dev (r3645)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
```

Maybe you can use that somehow. I think in PHP it's exposed in mysql_get_server_info() - extracted from the protocol when first connected.